# Heap memory full in Hazelcast jet

Tags: hazelcast, producer-consumer, hazelcast-jet

I have a client and server application, where the client is receiving data from the server using **WebSockets**.

Client application is built using **Hazelcast Jet** to process data provided by server. ClientApplication stores data inside Queue and polls it when it is ready to process further. Client is relatively slow compared to server, so data is continuously inserted in client's Queue until the heap is full. I wonder if there are any Hazelcast Jet features which I can use to resolve this issue.

**Note**: I don't want the producer to stop producing data or the client to stop receiving it. I want to client to continue receiving the data and process it as fast as possible.

The solution I have in mind is to write data received from server into a file rather than storing in Queue and read data from it, this can resolve the memory issue. Is this the proper way to handle this use case or there are better solutions to this?

Comment: i am using com.aol.simple.react.async.Queue;

Comment: There's nothing in Jet you can use to persist data while the downstream stages slowly process them. The usual way is to apply backpressure. In your case it might be to NOT read from the websocket. If the software at the other end isn't able to handle backpressure, you need to replace your queue with one that can persist.

Comment: Then storing data inside a file and read from is the way to solve this issue?

Comment: You're asking very vague questions, but yes, if you are low on memory, then saving to file is a way to address it, obviously.